# Double integrals as areas

Tags: integration

Im trying to get my head around the concept of double integrals to compute an area. We are given the curve in polars as $\frac{3}{2}\leq r \leq 1+\cos\phi$. I got this to look like the arc of a circle going from $\frac{-\pi}{3}\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$. My attempt to calculate the area of the curve is as follows $$2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\int_{\frac{3}{2}}^{1+\cos\phi}rdrd\phi$$ Which gives an answer of $\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}-\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is this method in general correct or should the upper limit of the inner integral be $2$? Many thanks.

Comment: I think the lower limit of the inner integral should be $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Ah yes! I had that on my working on paper, but copied it incorrectly into the latex format.

Comment: And it should be $d\phi$ instead of $d\theta$.

Comment: Was getting too used to writing $d\theta$. Corrected now.

Comment: It is correct then.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much!